# Should I disable WCF reliable sessions for Intranet scenarios?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, ws-reliablemessaging, reliable-message-delivery

The scenario is a web server in a DMZ that talks to a WCF server for all database related calls.

All calls are server to server in an intranet, either over netTcp or wsHttp from a ASPX page which calls an SVC service.

Theoretically speaking, should I take action to disable the reliable session features, or should I enable them, or would it make no difference?

It appears that reliable sessions introduces configuration risks (i.e. failures because WCF is so difficult to configure).

This is problematic if there never is a message that fails to go from one intranet server to the other, or if there never is an out-of-order message.

I wish I could load test this and monitor for the existence of dropped messages, but my available test environments are way different from the production environment with respect to network reliability.

**Note**: The users are not using WCF clients, they are just using ordinary web browsers talking to an ASPX page, all WCF activity is on the intranet side of the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

According to msdn:

If your scenario has any of the following characteristics, then you should consider using a WCF reliable session:

1. SOAP intermediaries, such as SOAP routers.
2. Proxy intermediaries or transport bridges.
3. Intermittent connectivity.
4. Sessions over HTTP.

I think it doesn't make sense whether intranet or DMZ, so it depends on your requirement.